# How to add the 'Open as Administrator' option for an app in the App Bar?

Tags: windows-8.1

I have laptop with Windows 8.1 64-bits.

My AppBar looks like this:

[image]

I often need to use the *Open as Administrator* option for the command prompt; how can I do this with a **right click**?

Now I only have to options for the right click: *Command Prompt* and *Remove this program form the App Bar*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open your command prompt, hover your mouse over the icon in the task bar, a thumbnail should appear.
2. Right click on the thumbnail and click on properties.
3. Goto the capabilities tab.
4. Check the option of "Always run this program as administrator".